# admin customer Edit form is not getting record id in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, phpstorm

I am new to magento, I have created custom module front and backend(admin) module, working fine except edit.

in grid bind the data correctly with id

`http://localhost/magento/index.php/test/adminhtml_index/edit/id/1/key/ef47aec44d98d1201d27fcdc732243a3`.

but when I click on edit I redirected to edit page and I did debug also, but record id is not getting.

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $testId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('test_id');
        //id is not getting
        Mage::log($testId);
        $testModel = Mage::getModel('quotes/quotes')->load($testId);
      .....
    }
```

if I pass/hard coded from here I got a details of record id

```
$testModel = Mage::getModel('quotes/quotes')->load(1);
```

can any one tell me where I went wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

What index did you give your entity?

```
$id  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

I usually use `id` as a primary key, and am able to load it by getting the associated paramter.

As per comment:

```
public function editAction()
{
    $testId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('test_id');
    $testModel = Mage::getModel('quotes/quotes')->load($testId);
    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getQuotesData(true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $testModel->setData($data);
    }  
 
    Mage::register('quotes_quotes', $testModel);
    $this->_initAction()
        ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('quotes_quotes/adminhtml_quotes_edit')->setData('action', $this->getUrl('*/*/save')))
        ->renderLayout();
}
```

Then in your form file

`app/code/codepool/Quotes/Quotes/Block/Adminhtml/Quotes/Edit/Form.php`

```
...
 protected function _prepareForm()
{  
    $model = Mage::registry('adminhtml');
     $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'        => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('test_id'))),
        'method'    => 'post'
    ));
    
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
        'legend'    => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Quotes'),
        'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
    ));
 
    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'id',
        ));
    }  
...
```

Comment: my primary key is `test_id`. here I am not getting record id.

Comment: So when you click the record in grid view, you get directed to the edit page but the fields aren't populated with the data?

Comment: yah! if i hard code I got result otherwise not getting.

Comment: see the updated answer, let me know if that proves useful

Comment: from where i write this code.

Comment: Insert it just after you declare your model:

`$testModel = Mage::getModel('quotes/quotes')->load($testId);`

I've edited the answer to suite your case in specific

Comment: Have a look at this guide too: http://codegento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/